# Is peanut butter a choking hazard for animals?

Tags: zoology

I've run into the statement, usually on pet forums, that you shouldn't feed peanut butter to dogs or small rodents like hamsters or rats  because it's a choking hazard (I've also heard long-term health claims, but I don't want to address that here). However, I've been baiting mouse and rat traps with peanut butter for years. It's very common to find traps with bait missing the next day, but I've never seen an animal dead next to the trap who may have choked to death.

Are there any verified cases of animals choking on peanut butter, whether they live or die from the experience? Or better, any statistics on how likely it is to happen vs times the animal eats peanut butter?

Comment: Perhaps asking this at pets.stackexchange would be better ?

Comment: The way I've heard it, peanut butter is a choking hazard for *humans*.

Comment: When I lived in a place that had mice, peanut butter was the best bait by far for catching mice. But said mice were usually killed by the trap before they could get around to choking on the peanut butter.